# XSL: how to define namespace tns

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I am trying to convert an application from Java 5 to java8 and from jboss5 to wildfly10
This did not give us any issues before as far as I know

```
<xsl:if test="name()='xsd:schema'">
    <xsl:attribute name="targetNamespace">http://ws.mycomp.com/obfustream/</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="xmlns:tns">http://ws.mycomp.com/obfustream/</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
```

the first line goes fine but the second line fails with error:

> ERROR:  'line 13: You cannot call an attribute 'xmlns:tns''

Comment: Looks as if you were relying on a bug in the XSLT processor and the bug has been fixed. You can't use xsl:attribute to create namespaces. Also, the test on `name()` here is highly questionable, since it relies on the choice of namespace prefix. Much better would be `test="self::xsd:schema"`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
I added :
xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  in the

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
```

and added

```
<xsl:attribute name="tns:type">http://ws.gbst.com/clearview/</xsl:attribute>
```

in

```
  <xsl:if test="name()='xsd:schema'">
    <xsl:attribute name="targetNamespace">http://ws.mycomp.com/obfustream/</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="tns:type">http://ws.mycomp.com/obfustream/</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
```